# Combining two different eows of the same query into one

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table similar to this

```
Id | student_name | grade_Sem_A | grade_sem_b
```

I need to get the following table as a result

```
Student_name | grade | Semester
```

To do that I use the following query

```
select student_name, grade_sem_a as grade, 'A' as sem 
union all
select student_name, grade_sem_b as grade, 'B' as sem
```

The problem is that it queries the exact same rows twice, which is unnecessary,  and the table I am using has tons of rows and each of these queries takes a long time on its on, is there a way to get the exact same result without using union all and query the same data twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest this:

```
select student_name, grade_sem as grade, sem 
from your_table,
(
  select 'A' as sem from dual
  union all
  select 'B' as sem from dual
  ) t;
```

my explain plain shows the access of main table is done once.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem is grade_sem is not a row, there is grade_sem_a and grade_sem_b

Comment: try this: select case when sem = 'A' then grade_Sem_A
       else grade_sem_b end
       from (

select student_name, grade_sem_a grade seb_b, sem
from your_table
,
(
  select 'A' as sem from dual
  union all
  select 'B' as sem from dual
  ) t);

Comment: or this:  select case when sem = 'A' then grade_Sem_A
       else grade_sem_b end,student_name,sem from your_table
,
(
  select 'A' as sem from dual
  union all
  select 'B' as sem from dual
  ) t;